# If I retrain the feat Skill Training, do I then lose training in that skill?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, skills, retraining

Let's say at level 2, I choose to learn the feat Skill Training and add a +5 training bonus to Dungeoneering. Then at level 11, I retrain it with a Paragon level feat. Do I then lose the training bonus to Dungeoneering?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you lose the training (assuming you have nothing else that is granting you training). The feat grants you training in a skill, and if you retrain it you no longer gain its benefits.

Comment: Would you then get to pick a new skill for the Feat to affect? Or is the Feat lost/wasted at that point?

Comment: No, since you no longer *have* the feat.

Comment: @Rayanth Retraining the feat is effectively replacing it with a different feat. It is lost, but you gain the other feat you retrained into instead.

Comment: My apologies, my brain for some reason was interpreting the OP's question entirely wrong. I thought they were asking if you retrain the skill that the feat is affecting.